# Redirect output of sys process to stdout, no buffering

Tags: scala, unix

I would like to run an external process and have its stdout and stderr piped immediately to stdout, without any buffering (at least not line-buffering). With line buffering, this isn't difficult:

```
val cmd: String = ...
cmd ! ProcessLogger(println,println)
```

However, how can I do this so that I don't have to wait for a whole line before outputting? The problem is that the process I am running has a percentage output that keeps updating, but when I use something like the above, it waits for a bit and then finally outputs `100%`.

I've looked into `ProcessIO` and the helpful `BasicIO` companion, but I haven't managed to get anything working end to end.